# Styled-components: React does not recognize the `lineHeight` prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

```
const props = {
  lineHeight: 1.4
};

const Out = styled(OutContainer)`
  height: 77px;
`;

Out.defaultProps = props;
```

And the error:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `lineHeight` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `lineheight` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

I am new to styled-components. What am I missing?

Comment: What is `OutContainer` ? Can you add the code please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following solution?

```
const props = {

    style : {
        lineHeight: 1.4
    }
}
```